# PlaceId from Google Map, different from iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I have apps which using google maps. iOS has `GoogleMaps=6.2.1`, android has:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.2.3'
```

On both devices maps works good, but i faced with problem related with Point Of Interested id, and i cant find information why it happens.

So, for example, in iOS i have listener which return information about clicked place:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapPOIWithPlaceID placeID: String, name: String, location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    // placeID will be ZhDJA-k2Ym_pPkcFG1VfPvb99Vv, good ID
}
```

Example in Android, android has also listener, which return information about clicked place:

```
override fun onPoiClick(poi: PointOfInterest) {
    // poi.placeId - will be like ZhDJAAAAAAAAAAA1VfPvb99Vv, bad ID
}
```

I clicked in the same place in iOS and Android, but android in some reason replace part of placeId to AAAAAAA.

but if in **Android** i will do additional request

```
    placesClient.fetchPlace("ZhDJAAAAAAAAAAA1VfPvb99Vv", listOf(Place.Field.ID))
    .addOnSuccessListener { response: FetchPlaceResponse ->
// response.place.id - now it ZhDJA-k2Ym_pPkcFG1VfPvb99Vv like in iOS without any additional requests
        }
```

I will get normal placeID which in iOS i have without additional requests.

**Why Google Map in Android and Google Map on iOS returns different placeID ?**